# clojurescript (js* "c=1") does not work

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

This has been bugging me for a while. At the repl I can type:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (js* "window")
==> #<[object DOMWindow]>
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (js* "window.a=1")
==> 1
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (js* "window.a")
==> 1
```

But if I type:

```
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (js* "c=1")
==> 1
ClojureScript:cljs.user> (js* "c")
=>       ; expect 1 but returns nothing
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

js* is an implementation detail, you shouldn't be using it at all.

Comment: We're all adults here =) I see it used in quite a few libraries and it would be nice to know a little bit more about it as opposed to the 'don't touch that you'll hurt yourself!' answer.

Comment: It may be removed entirely in the future. No library should rely on it.